# How to configure autoscaling for type: Object

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

I have a custom metrics configured.

When I run:

`kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/my-namespace/deployments.extensions/sample-app/queue_length" | jq`

I got:

```
...
  "items": [
    {
      "describedObject": {
        "kind": "Deployment",
        "namespace": "my-namespace",
        "name": "sample-app",
        "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1"
      },
      "metricName": "queue_length",
      "timestamp": "2018-10-09T18:14:15Z",
      "value": "30"
    }
  ]
...
```

So I want to scale my deployment with this metric:

```
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
metadata:
  name: sample-app
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: sample-app
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Object
    object:
      metricName: queue_length
      target:
        apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
        kind: Deployment
        name: sample-app
      targetValue: 20
```

But it doesn't seem to work, maybe I have to specify `- type: Object` somewhat different.

I tried to change `kind` to deployments, deployments.extension, deployments.extensions etc, but I keep getting error `FailedGetScale`

**Upd.:** I figured out that namespace for HPA object and target object should be the same, so I changed it. And now I'm getting

```
the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: unable to get metric queue_length: Deployment on default sample-app/unable to fetch metrics from custom metrics API: the server could not find the metric queue_length for deployments.extensions sample-app
```

**Upd2.:** Figured it out: hpa was in namespace `default`, while metric was exposed to `my-namespace`. So, should be careful with namespaces!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
---
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
metadata:
  name: sample-app
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: sample-app
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Object
    object:
      target:
        kind: Service
        name: sample-app
      metricName: queue_length
      targetValue: 20
```

Comment: Tried, but it doesn't work either:
`ScalingActive  False   FailedGetObjectMetric  the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: unable to get metric celery_production_yodlee: Service on default sample-app/unable to fetch metrics from custom metrics API: the server could not find the metric celery_production_yodlee for services.extensions`. And since I have API path `namespaces/my-namespace/deployments.extensions/sample-app/queue_length` there should be `deployment` I think

Comment: Oh, bad. What is returning? kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/my-namespace/services/*/queue_length" | jq .